# C++ Vector trying to create histogram

Tags: c++, vector

So today I decided to write a simple  histogram using vector, however as I write this Program and compile it, the output shows a never ending of "*".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ios>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;



int main()
{
int x;
double k;
cout<<"How many range would you like = ";
    cin>>x;
vector<double> number; //All data was being stored here
cout<<"Input the number to be included in histogram = ";
while(cin>>k)
number.push_back(k);


x = x*10;
sort(number.begin(), number.end());


for(int i=0;i<x;i+=10) // Problem is on this loop statement, but I can't fix it.
{
    vector<double>::size_type u = 0;
    cout<<i<<"-"<<i+9<<" = "; //The range, Intended to put the "*" besides it.
    while(u < number.size())
     {
        if( number[u]<=i+9 && number[u]>=i)
        cout<<"*"; //For showing how many numbers on that range
        else
            u++;

    }
    cout<<endl;
}

getch();
return 0;
  }
```

There are no bugs shown, only the never ending of "*" on the first range.(example, when the programs compiled, I enter the data and it shows "0-9 =* *********" and it just keep on repeating without going to the next line. Any advice to fix this one?
EDIT: I tried to use iterator before, but it has the same output with this one.

Comment: `else u++;`? remove the else.

Comment: Thank you so much itwasntpete! I still need to train more on my logic it seems.

Answer (score 1):

So, in your `while` loop...

```
if( number[u]<=i+9 && number[u]>=i)
    cout<<"*";
```

You've got that code.  The issue is, you only increment `u` in the `else` part of your `if else` within this `while` loop.  So if you go into the `while` loop and this `if` condition returns `true`, it will stay `true` for ever.  You'll be stuck in the `while` loop executing `cout<<"*";` forever because you do nothing to change the value of `u` here.

Comment: Yeah, I overlook such simple thing. Thanks for the input nhgrif!

Comment: Setting breakpoints is a good way to find simple errors like this.  With a breakpoint, you would've quickly spotted the value of `u` was never changing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
if( number[u]<=i+9 && number[u]>=i)
    cout<<"*"; //For showing how many numbers on that range
else
    u++;
```

Once you find a number in range, the `else` means that you won't move on to the next number; you'll stay there, printing `*`, forever.

You could simply remove the `else`; or you could structure it as a `for` loop, which might make it more obviously correct:

```
for (size_t u = 0; u < number.size(); ++u)
```

or, since 2011, a new-style `for` loop:

```
for (double n : number) {
    if (n < i+10 && n >= i) {
        cout << "*";
    }
}
```

I also took the liberty of fixing the logic so that, for example, `9.5` isn't excluded.